# Why is `ctypes` slower than extending python?

Tags: python

I have implemented a simple recursive fibonacci function in C, and created python bindings using the two main scenarios

- using `ctypes`
- extending python with module written in C

I realise that with `ctypes` the conversion happens on python side, and so it is expected to have higher overhead for a function call.

However, the overhead would become negligible for long running functions. The result I get is the opposite. By averaging multiple calls, for `fibonacci(5)`, ctypes is two times slower. However, for `fibonacci(50)` it is nearly 3 times slower. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Their performance should absolutely be the same as long as the native code inside the function being called is the same. Maybe you are using different optimization flags?

Comment: Also, a good experiment might be to export a fib function inside the C extension, compile the C extension without importing it, and then load the function using ctypes.

Comment: @FilipDimitrovski: thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I have noticed myself, and I am not sure, but my hypothesis is that the assignment of the ctype arrays in C triggers operations in Python, similar to the PyArray_FROM_OTF function in the extension setup. So, it might seem like you would do such operations for all assignments in ctypes, but only for the calls to PyArray_FROM_OTF in C-extension. Would be great if someone with knowledge could confirm or reject this hypothesis.